# How to make "controls" on a web page that get real time data updates

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am a total newbie to web ASP .NET Core MVC programming and see all these examples of bootstrap and forms with list boxes and simple controls.

In the old days, we used to have active x containers with custom controls that could acquire real time data updates, we used CORBA back then.

Is there any functional equivalent in WEB ASP programming? Does an individual HTTP request have to be sent every time an update is wanted? I'd like to have the server objects on the back end decide when it is time to send a change-driven data update.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, you can't do this easily, however there's a library for it called [SignalR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SignalR).

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Server-Sent-Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events).